# R: Different apply function per column based on column name

Tags: r, function, apply

I have a dataframe structured as:

```
  ID   X1   X2  X3   X4   X5
1  1  grn gerp hrn  asn  bln
2  2 asn   bln hgv  mpl  zwl
3  3  zwl  mpl lwd <NA> <NA>
4  4  bln  asn hrn gerp  grn
5  5  lwd  mpl zwl <NA> <NA>
```

I'm using currently an insufficient method to check if a row contains a word in the following wordlist:

```
wordlist <- c("asn", "bln", "gerp", "grn", "hgv", "hrn", "lwd", "mpl", "zwl")
```

By using the method below I get a TRUE or FALSE if the row ID contains the word in the row:

```
newDF <- as.data.frame(DF[,1])
newDF[, wordlist] <- NA

newDF[2] <- apply(DF, 1, function(r) any(r %in%  as.character(wordlist[1])))
newDF[3] <- apply(DF, 1, function(r) any(r %in%  as.character(wordlist[2])))
newDF[4] <- apply(DF, 1, function(r) any(r %in%  as.character(wordlist[3])))
newDF[5] <- apply(DF, 1, function(r) any(r %in%  as.character(wordlist[4])))
newDF[6] <- apply(DF, 1, function(r) any(r %in%  as.character(wordlist[5])))
newDF[7] <- apply(DF, 1, function(r) any(r %in%  as.character(wordlist[6])))
newDF[8] <- apply(DF, 1, function(r) any(r %in%  as.character(wordlist[7])))
newDF[9] <- apply(DF, 1, function(r) any(r %in%  as.character(wordlist[8])))
newDF[10] <- apply(DF, 1, function(r) any(r %in%  as.character(wordlist[9])))
```

Resulting in the following dataframe:

```
 DF[, 1]   asn   bln  gerp   grn   hgv   hrn   lwd   mpl   zwl
1       1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
2       2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
3       3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
4       4  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
5       5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

As you see this method is quite inefficient, especially as I have to apply this method to a much bigger DF and a wordlist of 400 words.

**Main question:** (EDIT: SOLVED)

- Is there an efficient way to get the same result?

**Sub question:**

- Is it possible to not output TRUE or FALSE but an index of the word where the word is in the row of DF?

The dataframe to try:

```
    > dput(DF)
        structure(list(ID = 1:5, X1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("asn ", "bln", "grn", "lwd", "zwl"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("asn", "bln", "gerp", "mpl"), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("hgv", "hrn", 
    "lwd", "zwl"), class = "factor"), X4 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
    NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("asn", "gerp", "mpl"), class = "factor"), X5 = structure(c(1L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("bln", "grn", 
    "zwl"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `match`

```
t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) sapply(wordlist, function(y) 
    ifelse(is.na(match(y, x)), FALSE, TRUE))))
#       asn   bln  gerp   grn   hgv   hrn   lwd   mpl   zwl
#[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Or to get the column *name* of `DF` of the matched word

```
t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) sapply(wordlist, function(y)
    ifelse(match(y, x), paste0("X", match(y, x) - 1), NA))))
#     asn  bln  gerp grn  hgv  hrn  lwd  mpl  zwl
#[1,] "X4" "X5" "X2" "X1" NA   "X3" NA   NA   NA
#[2,] NA   "X2" NA   NA   "X3" NA   NA   "X4" "X5"
#[3,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "X3" "X2" "X1"
#[4,] "X2" "X1" "X4" "X5" NA   "X3" NA   NA   NA
#[5,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "X1" "X2" "X3"
```

Or to get the column *index* in `DF` of the matched word

```
t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) sapply(wordlist, function(y) match(y, x))))
#     asn bln gerp grn hgv hrn lwd mpl zwl
#[1,]   5   6    3   2  NA   4  NA  NA  NA
#[2,]  NA   3   NA  NA   4  NA  NA   5   6
#[3,]  NA  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA   4   3   2
#[4,]   3   2    5   6  NA   4  NA  NA  NA
#[5,]  NA  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA   2   3   4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the main question of my problem.

Comment: @Menn0 I completely missed the second part of your question. Please see my updated answer.